# R - fastest way to look at all unique pairs of columns

Tags: r, plyr, apply, correlation, lapply

I have a data frame, M, and I want to calculate all pairwise correlations between the columns of M. I can do this easily using apply functions, e.g.

```
pvals = laply(M, function(x) llply(M, function(y) cor.test(x, y)$p.value))
```

However, this solution is doing 2x the required work because the correlation between x and y is the same as the correlation between y and x.

I am looking for a fast, simple way to calculate all correlations among unique pairs of columns. I would like the result to be an NxN matrix, where N=ncol(M). I've searched on Stack Overflow for a long time, but couldn't find anything that did this. Thanks!

Comment: I've thought about using apply statements over i=1:n and j=1:i, but then I have trouble mapping everything back to its correct position in an NxN matrix. If anyone knows how to do this, it would solve my question. Thanks!

Comment: Could you make a small example data set, `M`?

Comment: `?expand.grid` and `?combn` and surely these have been asked before, so you really should do some searching as requested.

Comment: I don't know the difference between correlations (1 on the diagonal) and the output of cor.test (0 on the diagonal). If you want the former, there is an easy way to do it using matrix multiplications.

Comment: Yep! x = data.frame(replicate(10,rnorm(25))); rownames(x) = 1:25; colnames(x) = letters[1:10]. Then, I want to get all correlations between a,b,...,j.

Comment: You should adjust the resulting p-values for multiple testing.

Answer (score 5):

for the iris data, you can do:

```
data(iris)
r <- cor(iris[1:4])
```

to get the correlation matrix.

You can look at what `cor.test` actually does with `stats:::cor.test` and find this...

```
    df <- n - 2L
    ESTIMATE <- c(cor = r)
    PARAMETER <- c(df = df)
    STATISTIC <- c(t = sqrt(df) * r/sqrt(1 - r^2))
    p <- pt(STATISTIC, df)
```

which is all vectorized, so you can just run it.

There's a good discussion of the different tests on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient

Comment: For the two-sided test you'll also need `p <- 2 * pmin(p, 1 - p)`.

Comment: Sorry, a little confused... Does this calculate the correlation for A vs B, and again for B vs A? Or does it only calculate the correlation once?

Comment: @ab - `cor()` calculates the correlation matrix for the set of variables, which does exploit symmetry.  The rest just transforms it into a p-value.

Comment: `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` would be useful for getting only one set of correlations and eliminating the other half of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `combn`:

```
#Some data:
DF <- USJudgeRatings
#transform to matrix for better subset performance:
m <- as.matrix(DF)
#use combn and its `FUN` argument: 
res <- matrix(nrow=ncol(DF), ncol=ncol(DF))
res[lower.tri(res)] <- combn(seq_along(DF), 2, function(ind) cor.test(m[, ind[[1]]], m[, ind[[2]]])$p.value)
res[upper.tri(res)] <- t(res)[upper.tri(res)]
diag(res) <- 0
```

## Benchmarks:

```
corpRoland <- function(DF) {
  m <- as.matrix(DF)
  res <- matrix(nrow=ncol(DF), ncol=ncol(DF))
  res[lower.tri(res)] <- combn(seq_along(DF), 2, function(ind) cor.test(m[, ind[[1]]], m[, ind[[2]]])$p.value)
  res[upper.tri(res)] <- t(res)[upper.tri(res)]
  diag(res) <- 0
  res}

corpNeal <- function(DF) {
  cors <- cor(DF)
  df <- nrow(DF)-2
  STATISTIC <- c(t = sqrt(df) * cors/sqrt(1 - cors^2))
  p <- pt(STATISTIC, df)
  matrix(2 * pmin(p, 1 - p),nrow=ncol(DF))}


library(microbenchmark)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e3), ncol=10))
microbenchmark(corpRoland(DF), corpNeal(DF))
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr       min         lq    median       uq       max neval
# corpRoland(DF) 14021.003 14228.2040 14950.212 15157.27 17013.574   100
#   corpNeal(DF)   342.631   351.6775   373.636   385.34   467.773   100

DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1e4), ncol=100))
microbenchmark(corpRoland(DF), corpNeal(DF), times=10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#           expr         min          lq      median          uq         max neval
# corpRoland(DF) 1595.878487 1601.221980 1615.391891 1633.746678 1637.373231    10
#   corpNeal(DF)    8.359662    8.751755    9.021532    9.509576    9.753154    10
```

So, you should use the answer by @NealFultz.

Comment: I don't know if diag should be one or zero, but you can initialize it to that in the initial `matrix(1,...` I guess.

Comment: It depends on the alternative. It's zero for the two.sided test, see `cor.test(1:5,1:5)`.